# Read parent child node relation from XML in Postgress

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, postgresql-14

I wanted to get parent node name and list of child nodes. Below is sample list of XML inputs:

```
<Base>
<Data>
<T1Container>
<foo>
  <bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar>
</foo>
</T1Container>
<T2Container>
<foo1><bar1>test3</bar><zar1>test4</zar2></foo1>
</T2Container>
</Data>
</Base>';
```

For above input XML, output should be

```
create table foo columns bar, zar
create table foo1 columns bar1, zar1
```

I have created a function & inside that i am trying to create database table with parent name as table name and child nodes as table columns.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    container_node xml;
    table_node xml;
    table_name text;
    column_names text;
    column_node xml;
    xml_data xml := '<Base>
<Data>
<T1Container>
<foo>
  <bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar>
</foo>
</T1Container>
<T2Container>
<foo1><bar1>test3</bar><zar1>test4</zar2></foo1>
</T2Container>
</Data>
</Base>';
BEGIN
  FOR container_node IN SELECT unnest(xpath('/Base/Data/*[contains(name(), "Container")]', xml_data)) LOOP
     column_names := '';
     table_node := (xpath('./*', container_node))[1];
     RAISE NOTICE 'table_node: %', table_node; 
     table_name := name(table_node);

     FOR column_node IN SELECT unnest(xpath('./*[position() > 0]', container_node)) LOOP   
         column_names := column_names || name(column_node) || ', ';
         --RAISE NOTICE 'Column Name: %', name(column_node);
     END LOOP;

     column_names := rtrim(column_names, ', ');

     -- psuedo cod efor table creation  -- to do 

END LOOP;
END $$;
$$;
```

But after this not getting correct table_node and related column_names. Why name (table_node / column_names) are not working?

I'm using Postgress PostgreSQL 14.1 on DBeaver on Linubox.